# Pandas dataframe with Greek characters to postgresql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, encoding

I'm working with the following:
Python 3.9.2
Pandas 1.3.4
PostgreSQL 14.1

I have created a sample dataframe to explore pandas and postgresql.

```
d = {'col1': ['Αθήνα', 'χαρύϊψχορες'], 'col2': ['Θεσσαλονίκη', 'Ξπφδ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Working on Jypiter when I call df, I get the following output:

```
    col1    col2
0   Αθήνα   Θεσσαλονίκη
1   χαρύϊψχορες Ξπφδ
```

Then, I try to add the data to psql, using the following code:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost:port/test_db', encoding='utf-8-sig')
df.to_sql('sq_exp', engine)
```

The if I open my CMD to select the data, I get this error:

```
test_db=# select * from sq_exp;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xce 0x91 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

While trying to fix this error, I set the encoding to win1252 only to get the same error:

```
test_db=# SET client_encoding TO 'WIN1252';
SET
test_db=# select * from sq_exp;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xce 0x91 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

Following the documentation of postgres, I am setting the encoding to WIN1253
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html

The when I select the data: `select * from sq_exp;` I get the following output:

```
test_db=# select * from sq_exp;
 index |    col1     |    col2
-------+-------------+-------------
     0 | ┴Φ▐φß       | ╚σ≤≤ßδ∩φ▀Ωτ
     1 | ≈ß±²·°≈∩±σ≥ | ╬≡÷Σ
```

As you can see this is completely different from the df initially created and I have trying multiple approaches to solve it. Can please someone guide me thought how it can be done?

Thanks a lot!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkK3R.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49rAe.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wIoq.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsHVM.png

Comment: Are you sure about PostgreSQL 9.3 ? That's very old and outdated. What version are you using? And please, don't use images, just put the plain text in your question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks for checking. You are right, I have updated the question with the plain text. The version of PostgresSQL that I'm using is 14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually discovered the issue.

It seems that the CMD is not supporting the Greek characters and that's why the error is returned:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xce 0x91 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

The resolution is actually to view your data your code editor or database administration tool.

Here is an example using Visual Studio code:

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='database_name' user='postgres' password='password'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sq_exp")
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

Running the above will actually print you the expected output:

```
[(0, 'Αθήνα', 'Θεσσαλονίκη'), (1, 'χαρύϊψχορες', 'Ξπφδ')]
```

The same would apply using a database application tool